# Twitter Typeahead autocomplete on dynamic input fields

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, typeahead.js

I was wondering if there is anyone who has an idea of implementing twitter's typeahead autocomplete functionality on dynamic rows inputs?

Please help,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

@Jack Try the example from this url, the first one. Give your input the class calling the function. 
[Check this Example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

example: `$('#your-input-box').typeahead({  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
});`